# Cardinality of direct product of Sylow $p$-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group such that, for all prime number $p$, $P_p$ is a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Let $I$ denote the set of prime numbers dividing $|G|$ and
$$K=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{g\ |\ (\exists x)(x\in(\bigcup_{p\in I} P_p)^{[1,n]}\ \&\ g=x_1\ldots x_n)\}.$$

Then $G=K$. I have to prove that

> $$|\prod_{p\in I} P_p|=G.$$

For $p\in I$, let $i_p:P_p\rightarrow\prod_{p\in I} P_p$ be the canonical injection. Then $\prod_{p\in I} P_p=\langle\bigcup_{p\in I} i_p(P_p)\rangle$. On the other hand, let $\phi_p:P_p\rightarrow i_p(P_p)$ be the isomorphism of $P_p$ onto $i_p(P_p)$. We can extend the family $(\phi_p)_{p\in I}$ of isomorphisms to a unique isomorphism $\phi:\cup P_p\rightarrow \cup i_p(P_p)$. This shows that
$$|\bigcup P_p|=|\bigcup i_p(P_p)|.$$

Can I conclude $|\langle\bigcup_{p\in I} P_p\rangle|=|\langle\bigcup_{p\in I} i_p(P_p)\rangle|$ from this? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose
$$|G|=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_m^{k_m}$$
with the $p_i$ distinct primes. Then
$$|P_{p_i}|=p_i^{k_i}$$
by definition of a Sylow subgroup. The order of the direct product of all of these is therefore the order of $G$.

Comment: Ah your proof is so simple! thanks

Comment: @user766969 No problem.